# When do I need to chain multiple CompletableFutures?

Tags: java, multithreading

Is there any advantage of chaining multiple futures over single block of code?

Since every CompletableFuture needs previous result in a chain, I think there is no performance difference between them.

Here is a single block;

```
CompletableFuture<String> future0= CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
    //code1
    //code2
    //code3
}, executorService);
```

Chain of CompletableFutures;

```
CompletableFuture<String> future1= CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
    //code1
}, executorService);

CompletableFuture<String> future2= stringCompletableFuture.thenApplyAsync(text -> {
    //code2
}, executorService);

CompletableFuture<String> future3= stringCompletableFuture.thenApplyAsync(text -> {
    //code3
}, executorService);
```

Comment: The futures run in parallel

Comment: The performance difference is all the `CompletableFuture` overhead of storing, finding, and invoking the handlers you register.

Comment: I think the point of the api, is if you have independent tasks that should be run asynchronous of other tasks, but in series of each other. Eg. To login, you query the DB, then start a session. To update your password, you query the db then update the password. Both methods query the db, and depend on it completing before they continue. So you wouldn't necessarily want to create a large block of code for each action that queries the db.